# Container View not available in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: xcode6, storyboard, uicontainerview

Does anyone have any idea why I wouldn't be able to find the Container View in Xcode when on a storyboard?  I've added on in this project, but now I can't seem to be able to add another one

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think container views are only available in storyboards.  If you are editing an individual view file (an xib), then containers are not available.